# Lo que se imprime por pantalla es menos de lo que deberia

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo un problema raro, estoy haciendo un programa simple en c++ que me pide contar el numero de cuadrados que introduzco y además mostrar su área y perímetro. Con el siguiente código.

El problema que me surge es que lo que se imprime por pantalla lo cual no es una variable es un string es cada vez menor a mayor numero sea lo que ingreso por teclado.

Si ingreso valores a la variable base o b valores muy grandes se come completamente la siguiente impresión por pantalla.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <exception> 
#include<vector>
#include"Square.h"

using namespace std;

static void introSquare(int& numSquare);
int main() {
    vector <string> opciones;
    opciones.push_back("Salir");
    opciones.push_back("Intorducir cuadrado");
    int opcion = 0;
    int contador = 0;


    // Programa para llamr a un cuadrado con una funcion , y manten la cuenta de cuantos cuadrados haces
    do {
        cout << "Hola que quieres hacer"<< endl;
        cout << "1. " + opciones.at(0) << endl;
        cout << "2. " + opciones.at(1) << endl;
        cin >> opcion;
        cin.clear();

        switch (opcion)
        {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            introSquare(contador);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Opcion inexistente trate de nuevo" << endl;
            break;
        }

    } while (opcion != 1);

}

 void introSquare(int& numSquare) {
    int b;
    ++numSquare;

    cout << " Cuadrado  numero " + numSquare << endl;
    cout << "Base ?" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cin.clear();
    
    try{
    Square cuadrado(b);
    cout << "El area del cuadrado es "+ cuadrado.getArea() << endl;
    cout << "El permitero del cuadrado es " + cuadrado.getPerimetre() << endl;
    }
    catch (string e) {
        cout << "el error es " + e << endl;
    }
}
```

Y el archivo de la clase Square.cpp y Square.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Square.h"


using namespace std;

Square::Square(int base) {
    this->base = base;
    if (base < 0)
        throw "La base nunca puede ser nagetiva";
}
int Square::getBase() { return base; }
void Square::setBase(int x) {
    base = x;
}
int Square::getArea( ) {
    return (getBase() * getBase());
}
int Square::getPerimetre() {
    return (getBase() + getBase() + getBase() + getBase());
}
void Square::print() {
    cout << "El area del cuadrado es " + this->getArea() << endl;
    cout << "El perimetro del cuadrado es " + this->getPerimetre() << endl;
}
```

```
class Square
{
private: 
    int base;

public: 
    Square(int);

    int getBase();
    void setBase(int);
    int getPerimetre();
    int getArea();
    void print();

};
```

Pero la salida que obtengo por pantalla es algo raro como esto

```
Hola que quieres hacer
1. Salir
2. Intorducir cuadrado
2
Cuadrado  numero
Base ?
1
l area del cuadrado es
ermitero del cuadrado es
Hola que quieres hacer
1. Salir
2. Intorducir cuadrado
2
uadrado  numero
Base ?
6
ermitero del cuadrado es
o es
Hola que quieres hacer
1. Salir
2. Intorducir cuadrado
1
```

Answer (score 2):

El error lo tienes a la hora de mandar los datos a `cout`. No puedes usar el operador `+` para concatenar datos:

```
cout << " Cuadrado  numero " + numSquare << endl; // mal

cout << " Cuadrado  numero " << numSquare << endl; // bien
```

Y aquí:

```
cout << "El area del cuadrado es "+ cuadrado.getArea() << endl;
cout << "El permitero del cuadrado es " + cuadrado.getPerimetre() << endl;
```

que sería:

```
cout << "El area del cuadrado es " << cuadrado.getArea() << endl;
cout << "El permitero del cuadrado es " << cuadrado.getPerimetre() << endl;
```